# Сохранить выбранный select в одной форме после отправки другой

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть две формы на странице, одна форма с селектом которая служит для вывода на страницу информации из бд в зависимости от выбранного option.
Вторая форма записывает в эту бд информацию.
После записи данных страница перезагружается, обновляется информация на странице из бд и сбрасывается значения селект, соответственно отображается информация из первого селекта.
Как сделать так что бы после отправки данных в бд, страница перезагрузилась, обновилась информация, но выбранный селект остался тем же??

Помогите, очень надо.

Comment: ну так не перегружай страницу, а данные отправляй аяксом

Comment: А данные на странице после добавления инфы в БД обновятся из БД без перезагрузки?

Comment: все что угодно можно сделать без перезагрузки страницы сайта))

Comment: нужна еще Ваша помощь.
С добавлением данных все получилось, а вот редактирование, никак через ajax, помогите пожалуйста